# Reference Object Member By String Name?

Tags: javascript, object

Sorry for the odd question name folks, I'm not sure I properly know how to phrase this question, but I am working with javascript, and would like to reference an objects member, but abstractly by string, is this possible in JavaScript? (or any language for that matter?) eg,..

The MemberName is determined when the function is run, could be 'Product Code' for example, but selected row will always represent a selected row in a grid. is this even possible? I am trying to create a generic function which will allow me to pass any grid to it, with the name of the column i want the value from - if that helps.

```
function GetSpecificColumnFromSelectedRow(SelectedRow, MemberName) {
    return SelectedRow.MemberName; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's rather easy:

```
SelectedRow[MemberName]
```

And you don't need a function to do it, which is why I didnt include your original function wrapper.

Comment: Laaawwrdd, is it that easy? will that approach work in C# as well?

Comment: I'd vote your comment up, but I need 15 rep to do so! But thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, but don't worry about the upvote. However, if you could mark the answer as correct it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would not expect so, as C# uses classes with predetermined structures.

However, in C# you could use a map to store dynamic content in an object.
Then it would be something like `SelectedRow.at(MemberName)`
I'm not too familiar with C# but this is the link to the Map class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s44w4h2s.aspx

Comment: @JosephDailey You can also use the dynamic ExpandoObject.

Comment: @Steven, Thanks for helping answer this subquestion, I dont know enough about C# to do it justice.

Comment: My site experience won't allow me to indicate its the correct answer to the question! Bah!

Comment: Jaamm, glad I could help. Good luck.